# I'm getting the following exception in Websphere Application Server when I attempt to create saml token(assertion)

Tags: java, websphere, saml, jce, opensaml

I'm getting the following exception in Websphere Application Server when I attempt to create SAML token (assertion) but its working on TomCat:

```
SignatureMars E org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.SignatureMarshaller createSignatureElement Unable to construct signature Element {http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}Signature
org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignatureException: The requested algorithm http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#dsa-sha1 does not exist. Original Message was: null
Original Exception was java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.xml.security.algorithms.SignatureAlgorithm.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xml.security.signature.SignedInfo.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.SignatureMarshaller.createSignatureElement(SignatureMarshaller.java:108)
at org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.SignatureMarshaller.marshall(SignatureMarshaller.java:69)
at org.opensaml.xml.io.AbstractXMLObjectMarshaller.marshallChildElements(AbstractXMLObjectMarshaller.java:316)
at org.opensaml.xml.io.AbstractXMLObjectMarshaller.marshallInto(AbstractXMLObjectMarshaller.java:224)
at org.opensaml.xml.io.AbstractXMLObjectMarshaller.marshall(AbstractXMLObjectMarshaller.java:130)
at org.opensaml.xml.io.AbstractXMLObjectMarshaller.marshall(AbstractXMLObjectMarshaller.java:86)
at com.opal.saml.SamlManager.signSamlAssertion(SamlManager.java:179)
at com.opal.saml.SamlManager.getResponse(SamlManager.java:152)
at com.opal.saml.SamlManager.generateToken(SamlManager.java:314)
at com.ibm._jsp._header._jspService(_header.java:116)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1384)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:104)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:852)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:785)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:234)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:644)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:1045)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:531)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor546.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtilImpl.doInclude(TilesUtilImpl.java:129)
at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtil.doInclude(TilesUtil.java:152)
at org.apache.struts.tiles.taglib.InsertTag.doInclude(InsertTag.java:764)
at org.apache.struts.tiles.taglib.InsertTag$InsertHandler.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:896)
```

Comment: IBM's JDK doesn't come with Sun's JCE. You can try Bouncy Castle JCE.

Comment: Please share the solution of this bug. I am also getting the same error.

Comment: Check this link [Signature verification methods](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7JFU_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/ae/twbs_confsignaturecon.html?cp=SS7JFU_8.5.5%2F1-3-0-15-3-0-3-1-1-1). Looks like it is not supported, you may try to reconfigure to use rsa-sha1 or hmac-sha1.